# Get Hive column names without table name in JDBC ResultSet metadata

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to get the name of the columns from the metadata of a `ResultSet` but in Hive I get column names if the form of `table_name.column_name` and I'd like to have only `column_name` (similarly to what I get from MySQL for example). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
There are two ways by which it can be done:

1.) Using Hive JDBC connection(which you are looking for).

2.) Using HiveMetastoreClient.

Here are code snippets for the above two approaches:

**First Approach:**

```
ResultSet resultSet = <custom_class_for_hive_jdbc_connector>.executeQuery("DESCRIBE <TABLE_NAME>");
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
while (resultSet.next()) {

System.out.println(" Column names : "+resultSet.getString(metaData.getColumnName(1)));

}
```

In this approach we need to create a resultsetmetadata object and using this object we can get the details of the query output. In your case "describe table"

**Second Approach:**

```
HiveMetaStoreClient metastoreClient = null;
HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();         
metastoreClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveConf);
List<FieldSchema> list = metastoreClient.getFields(<database_name>,<table_name>);   
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Column names : "+list.get(i).getName());        
}                   
metastoreClient.close();
```

In this approach we are not running any query, we are simply connecting to the HiveMetastore and from there we are getting the details of a given table under given database.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: Those alternatives certainly works. My question is why the HIVE driver returns a compound **table_name.column_name** when calling **ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName()**? As the method name implies it should return the column name only.  There is a designated **getTableName()** for the purpose of returning the table name. With these two properly implemented (getTableName() doesn't work either as it currently returns null) I can then decide to create a compound name. We've tested a lot of different databases and drivers and only run into this problem with HIVE.

Answer (score 0):

**To prevent the Hive table names from being prepended to the column names**, use this property setting in the Hive-site.xml file.

```
 <property>
   <name>hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names</name>
   <value>false</value>
 </property>
```

beginning with Hive .13, a new Hive property called `hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names` was created. The default value of this property is TRUE.

If the default value is used, the Hive table name is prepended to all column names. This is a change in behavior from previous versions of Hive.

This is also very important if you are trying to use Spring `Jdbctemplate` with `Beanpropertyrowmapper` to do the camel case to underscore format conversion for you.